# Details view doesn't work mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC 5 application. I follow up this tutorial [Getting Started with ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-details-and-delete-methods)

Altough when I click Details, Edit or Delete I get HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request.

My Index view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
 <div class="city">
 <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.announce_PublishDate)</h2>
 <p>@Truncate(item.announce_Description, 90)</p>
 <p>@Html.ActionLink("more", "Details", new { id = item.announce_ID }) </p></div>}
```

My Details view

```
<div>
<h4>prokirikseis</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.announce_ID)
    </dd>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.announce_Description)
    </dd>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.announce_PublishDate)
    </dd>

    </dl>
    </div>
      <p>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.announce_ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>
```

the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        announce announce= db.announce.Find(id);
        if (announce == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(announce);
    }
```

the model

```
public class announcements 
{
    [Key]
    public String announce_ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> announce_PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public String announce_Description { get; set; }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? I notice that it brings the right ID in the url. http://localhost:zzzzz/ltest/Details/01_2.2 but it does't bring the content.
thank you

Comment: `01_2.2` isn't a valid int...

Comment: thanks for your reply, I try with other id which are lets say 106. But it displays "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type of one of the primary key values did not match the type defined in the entity. See inner exception for details" I change the string to int in my model but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action methods are accepting a parameter which is typeof `int` but the key in class `announcements` is `string`, not `int`. (and the `url` in your question is passing a value of `01_2.2` to the `Details()` method so `id` is `null`).

Change your methods to

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
```

although I recommend you actually change the key to be an auto incremented `int`

Comment: What if I need the id to have characters like /. - and text. It doesn't work for this records. Do I need a new Maproute in my RouteConfig. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: That will be a problem - you would need to remove the `{id}` parameter from the route definition so that the generated url is `../test/details?id=yourValue` (i.e. the value is added as a query string rather than a route parameter. But why is your key a string?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply, It works. I will change my table so to have a normal ID. (it is an old table). thank you again.